# How to match regular expression characters in right position, wrong order?

Tags: python, regex

Say my string is `bucs`.
I would want to match **buc**caneer**s**, tampa bay **buc**caneer**s**, and **bucs**, but not "falcons".

I'm fairly new to regex, I tried:

```py
re.findall("bucs", "buccaneers")
```

and it returned an empty list.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for the individual letters to appear in the string in the order shown but not necessarily right next to one another?

Comment: In other words: there should be a `b`, and then a `u`, and then a `c`, and then a `s`, but in between each of those, there could be anything (zero or more characters)? Expressed that way, is it clear how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate your characters by `.*` to match strings in which they appear with no or some other characters between them:

```
In [1]: strs = "buccaneers", "tampa bay buccaneers", "bucs", "falcons"

In [2]: [s for s in strs if re.findall("b.*u.*c.*s", s)]
Out[2]: ['buccaneers', 'tampa bay buccaneers', 'bucs']
```